# Execute Python CGI from /cgi-bin/ folder

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

I have a standard Apache2 installation on an Ubuntu server. The default settings use `ScriptAlias` to refer `/cgi-bin/` to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/`. If I place my Python CGI script in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` it executes.

I created `/var/www/cgi-bin/` with appropriate permissions, removed the `ScriptAlias` line, changed the `Directory` entry in the `default` file for the site, moved the CGI file to `/var/www/cgi-bin/` and restarted Apache2, but I was not able to get the script to run. It was appearing as a text file in the browser instead of being executed. The HTML file calling the script refers to `/cgi-bin/SCRIPT`, so I left that unchanged. I tried variations on `/cgi-bin` and `/var/www/cgi-bin` in the config files without success. How can I get a Python CGI file to run *from* `/var/www/cgi-bin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you removed the `ScriptAlias` directive, you should probably add the following lines into the main config for the directory or into `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script py
```

Comment: My CGI scripts end in .cgi, so I presume that's ... `cgi-script cgi` in my case? I'll test it now.

Comment: I noticed that these lines did not work if I placed them under the `Directory` section in the `default` file; they worked when I placed them into the main body of that file. I presume it would be better to place them into a `.htaccess` file rather, so that their effects are local to that folder only?

Comment: @SabreWolfy, well, I do usually myself place them into `.htaccess` where I need =) But I have other `AddHandler` directives within `VirtualHost` sections, so they both should work.

Comment: @SabreWolfy, what is the `default` file within `Directory` section?

Comment: The `default` file is in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`; in there is the `<Directory>` section which refers to `/cgi-bin/` (which referred previously to the `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` folder). I have placed the lines into `/var/www/cgi-bin/.htaccess` and it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure:

1. the file you are calling itself has enough permission
2. the file you are calling has an extension that is is in the .htaccess file (see newtover's answer)
3. specify how you want to run the script in the first line of the file. If you are calling foo.pl, make sure #!/usr/bin/perl is in the first line.